# Why maven uses older version when there is a conflict between child projects?

Tags: java, maven, maven-reactor

In have one child module `testA` that has a dependency on vaadin-client-compiler that depends on commons-lang3 version 3.1, it also depends on another child module `testB` which depends on commons-lang3 version 3.4.

I expect `testA` to use the 3.4 version because `testB` depends on it but it uses the 3.1 version. I can solve it by adding `[]` to the version in `testB` project but why does it happen? Why maven doesn't resolve the correct version without being forced?

MCVE:

Parent:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>testB</module>
        <module>testA</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Child that depends

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <version>7.6.8</version>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>testB</groupId>
  <artifactId>testB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <groupId>testA</groupId>
  <artifactId>testA</artifactId>
</project>
```

And the dependent child

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>testB</groupId>
  <artifactId>testB</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: you should set dependencymanagement in the parent pom and manage the version there.

Comment: @PaulBastide This is an MCVE, my real projects are more complicated. Like I said in my question, I have a solution, I'm asking why this happens.

Comment: @PaulBastide Even with this example I disagree with your suggestion. I use and need the 3.4 version in `testB` and that's where it should be specified, I'm not using it anywhere else in other modules. `vaadin-client-compiler` needing it is not something I was even aware of before I encountered this problem.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes? This really hurts my feelings.

Comment: The solution is to use the dependencyManagement as mentioned by @PaulBastide the explanation is given in the Answer....

Comment: @khmarbaise Using `[3.4]` is also a solution as mentioned by me in my question.

Comment: I can not recommend to use that...better is to define it via dependencyManagement

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah, I agree with that. Does it make more sense to you to define it in `testA` or in the parent pom?

Comment: Do it in the parent pom that all childs can use it without a headache...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Maven Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> [Maven] will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies.

and

> if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.

So the answer to your question is - because you defined the `vaadin-client-compiler` dependency before the `testB` dependency and the dependency on `commons-lang3` is the same depth in the tree from `testA`.

If you reverse the order of your dependencies in `testA` you'll see that it now pulls the 3.4 version of `commons-lang3` (assuming you're using a version of Maven that is 2.0.9 or newer)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought maven takes the version of the dependency into consideration and uses the later one, that's how I would've implemented it. There is less chance for something to break if it would've been done this way.

Comment: You're quite welcome, but I'm not sure that using the latest version lessens the risk of problems in any significant way. It really depends on how the developers wrote the code and whether they planned for and tested backward compatibility.